Deploy blender script to be used as api on a web server
I have a website in Nextjs and a blender script that takes an image, a texture image and merge them together along with applying some visual effects like depth, render the result and return a png image of the rendered result to the frontend to be used in an img tag in the website.
I made a python flask app, installed blender, and made the route where I run blender as a subprocess, and it's working locally fine where I use the blender path for running the script in the subprocess.
However, on deploying to a linux server, I face a lot of errors, even after adding necessary libraries like mesa, libx, and trying to run it using xvfb.
My last trial was success with a digitalocean linux server and running blender using xvfb, hwoever it tokk 8  minutes just to render a geometric shape, which takes 1-2 seconds on a windows pc.
Can anyone help me deploy a python flask app with blender script, with regards to solving the common pitfalls of uisng a linux server, or recommend a hosting solution or type of server (aws linux with gpu...etc). Any help will be appreciated.
